# MacOS: Programmatically add some text to an image?

Tags: image, macos

I'm converting some code from linux to mac.

How can I programatically overlay an image with text, similar to the ImageMagick convert command?  For various reasons I can't depend on having ImageMagick installed.

```
convert -draw 'text 50,800 "hello world"' f1.png f2.png
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `NSImage` and `NSString` drawing APIs to create the edited image, and then use `NSBitmapImageRep` to get PNG data for the image. Example:

```
NSString *text = @"hello world";
NSImage *f1 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/f1.png"];
NSImage *f2 = [NSImage imageWithSize:f1.size flipped:YES drawingHandler:^BOOL(NSRect dstRect) {
    [f1 drawInRect:dstRect];

    // Attributes can be customized to change font, text color, etc.
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [NSFont systemFontOfSize:17]};
    [text drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(50, 800) withAttributes:attributes];

    return YES;
}];
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:[f2 CGImageForProposedRect:NULL context:nil hints:nil]];
NSData *data = [rep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
[data writeToFile:@"/path/to/f2.png" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: You neglected to draw `f1` into `f2`. Also, it's probably easiest to use old-style `lockFocus`, draw, `unlockFocus` to build `f2` and then create the data directly from its representations using `data = [NSBitmapImageRep representationOfImageRepsInArray:f2.representations usingType:NSPNGFileType properties:@{ }];`. Also, the calculation for the Y coordinate is pretty simple: `NSMaxY(dstRect) - 800`. Alternatively, you could just use a flipped image (pass `YES` to the flipped parameter in your code or use `lockFocusFlipped:YES` with my suggestion).

Comment: Fixed, thank you. What is the advantage of using `-lockFocus` rather than the newer API, besides backward compatibility?

Comment: I changed the answer back to using `-[NSBitmapImageRep initWithCGImage:]` for the time being because I tested the code using `-[NSBitmapImageRep representationOfImageRepsInArray:usingType:properties]` and it resulted in `<Error>: ImageIO: CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination must have at least one image` being logged and `nil` being returned. I tried this with both the new API and `-lockFocus`.

Comment: Yeah, I just did the same test and found the same thing. The idea behind my suggestion was that using `+imageWithSize:...` creates an image with a single representation of class `NSCustomImageRep` and I doubted that `+[NSBitmapImageRep representationOfImageRepsInArray:usingType:properties:]` would work with such a representation. My expectation was that locking focus and drawing would create a representation that would work. But as we've both now discovered, that was incorrect. Sorry about that.