# MacOS: Add a text overlay to an image in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, uikit, core-graphics

I've written a small extension for UIImage, which adds a text to an image:

```
extension UIImage {

    func addTextToImage(textToAdd: String) -> UIImage {
        let textColor = UIColor.white
        let textFont = UIFont(name: "Snell Roundhand", size: 40)!
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, scale)

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        var textFontAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
            ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]


        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.size))
        let textFrame = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/4, y: self.size.height/4)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: textFrame, size: CGSize(width: self.size.width/2, height: self.size.height/2) )
        text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
}
```

The result should look like this:
[image]

Now I want to do the same thing for NSImage to run on MacOS.

Any ideas how to do this?

All similar questions on Stackoverflow are either very old, unanswered or in Objective C

Comment: _"All similar questions on Stackoverflow are [...] or in Objective C"_ The API is still fundamentally the same.

Comment: The only question with an answer which I found is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790315/macos-programmatically-add-some-text-to-an-image

Comment: It is 4 years old and in the comments they are discussing about using an old API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
extension NSImage {

    func addTextToImage(drawText text: String) -> NSImage {

        let targetImage = NSImage(size: self.size, flipped: false) { (dstRect: CGRect) -> Bool in

            self.draw(in: dstRect)
            let textColor = NSColor.white
            let textFont = NSFont(name: "Snell Roundhand", size: 36)! //Helvetica Bold
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center

            var textFontAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
                ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

            let textOrigin = CGPoint(x: self.size.height/3, y: -self.size.width/4)
            let rect = CGRect(origin: textOrigin, size: self.size)
            text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
            return true
        }
        return targetImage
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this post for my radio-app. Something weird is going on. Who can help me out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75736665/texttoimage-shows-different-results-in-macos