# textToImage shows different results in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage

I use this code to place a text in an image:

```
extension NSImage {
     
     //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450429/macos-add-a-text-overlay-to-an-image-in-swift
     
     func textToImage(naam: String, slogan: String) -> NSImage {
          
         let targetImage = NSImage(size: self.size, flipped: false) { (dstRect: CGRect) -> Bool in

             let naamColor = NSColor.black

             let naamFont = NSFont(name: "Montserrat-SemiBold", size: 110)!
                         
             let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
             paragraph.alignment = .center
             
             let naamFontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: naamFont, .paragraphStyle: paragraph, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: naamColor] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

             let naamString = NSAttributedString(string: naam, attributes: naamFontAttributes)

             self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))

             let rectNaam = CGRect(x: 25, y: -25, width: self.size.width-25, height: self.size.height)
             
             naamString.draw(in: rectNaam)

             return true
                
         }
                
         return targetImage
          
     }
     
}
```

I use it in this way:

```
let image = loadImage(named: "eigenradiostation.png")
                
let imageWithText = image.textToImage(naam: radiostationGeselecteerd[0], slogan: radiostationGeselecteerd[1])

//downsample zodat widget niet > 16 MB komt
imageWithText.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

let imageData = imageWithText.tiffRepresentation!
                                    
recentAfgespeeldeRadiostationsTegels.insert(imageData, at:0)
```

I don't understand why the result differs from time to time. It looks that sometimes the imageWithText.size is executed first and then image.textToImage somehow?!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the usage from 1st adding text and 2nd resizing to 1st resizing and 2nd adding text. And that works somehow:

```
let image = loadImage(named: "eigenradiostation.png")
  
//downsample zodat widget niet > 16 MB komt
image.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
              
let imageWithText = image.textToImage(naam: radiostationGeselecteerd[0], slogan: radiostationGeselecteerd[1])

let imageData = imageWithText.tiffRepresentation!
                                    
recentAfgespeeldeRadiostationsTegels.insert(imageData, at:0)
```

I changed the font size and margins in the extension:

```
extension NSImage {
     
     //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450429/macos-add-a-text-overlay-to-an-image-in-swift
     
     func textToImage(naam: String, slogan: String) -> NSImage {
          
         let targetImage = NSImage(size: self.size, flipped: false) { (dstRect: CGRect) -> Bool in

             let naamColor = NSColor.black

             let naamFont = NSFont(name: "Montserrat-SemiBold", size: 12)!
                         
             let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
             paragraph.alignment = .center
             
             let naamFontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: naamFont, .paragraphStyle: paragraph, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: naamColor] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

             let naamString = NSAttributedString(string: naam, attributes: naamFontAttributes)

             self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))

             let rectNaam = CGRect(x: 5, y: -5, width: self.size.width-25, height: self.size.height)
             
             naamString.draw(in: rectNaam)

             return true
                
         }
                
         return targetImage
          
     }
     
}
```

Comment: The problem might be that you're using a fixed font size of 12 and depending on the size of the input image the text is proportionally bigger/smaller? Normalizing it before setting the text makes definitely sense (or setting the font size to 12/100 * image.size.height).

Comment: The image is always 800x800. This code worked before, but somehow it stopped working correctly. It works now, but I still don't understand why? Now I feed a 100x100 version of the 800x800 image and it works.

Comment: Hm if the input image always has the same size then idk what could cause this flaky havior :/

Comment: No idea, but it works now. Within different macos versions last 1+ year the behavior changed: version X oké, version y not oke?!